# 'START WITH' equivalent expression in MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, connect-by

Oracle SQL supports `START WITH` expression. 
For instance,

```
CREATE VIEW customers AS
SELECT LEVEL lvl, customer_code, customer_desc, customer_category 
FROM customers_master
START WITH some_column = '0'
CONNECT BY PRIOR CUSTOMER_CODE = PARENT_CUSTOMER_CODE;
```

If a table contains hierarchical data, then you can select rows in a hierarchical order using hierarchical query clauses.

`START WITH` specifies the root row(s) of the hierarchy.

`CONNECT BY` specifies the relationship between parent rows and child rows of the hierarchy.

Is there an equivalent expression for MS-SQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly. You can use recursive CTE (common table expressions) like the following, which requires a little bit more of writing:

```
;WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    -- Anchor (START WITH)
    SELECT
        customer_code, 
        customer_desc, 
        customer_category,
        Level = 1
    FROM
        customers_master AS C
    WHERE
        C.some_column = '0'

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive join
    SELECT
        C.customer_code, 
        C.customer_desc, 
        C.customer_category,
        Level = R.Level + 1
    FROM
        RecursiveCTE AS R -- Note that we are referencing a table that we are just declaring as CTE
        INNER JOIN customers_master AS C ON
            R.CUSTOMER_CODE = C.PARENT_CUSTOMER_CODE
)
SELECT
    R.*
FROM
    RecursiveCTE AS R
```

Will need to review the recursive join's columns a little bit, but you should get the idea.